# Aws amplify backend issue

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I am facing an issue with amplify while deploying back-end code using amplify push command. I've checked the `schema.graphql` file which appears to have the proper syntax. The problem appears to be with the `graphql` request file, so does anyone know where it's located?

[image: What the error looks like]

Comment: It looks like you have an error on line 58 of the GraphQL request.

Comment: but i can't able to find graphql request file . Could you help me to the find graphql request file in amplify stcture

Answer (score 0):

See if this is the one. From the [official documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/overview#update-schema):

```
backend/api/~apiname~/build/schema.graphql
```